# jQuery/HTML Match text of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

It's my first question here.

How to use regex (or any other better method) to match div A with div B (both having same text) on the basis of text inside them and then delete the matched div B?

Sample HTML ::

```
<div class="A"> Hello </div>
<div class="B"> Hello </div>
<div class="C"> Bye </div>
......... and so on.
```

Comment: What's the bigger issue here? Are you trying to remove consecutive divs with the same content?

Comment: Shikhars it's a bad idea to parse html with regex, you should use an html parser instead

Comment: No. The divs can be anywhere on the page jumbled up. I just want to match 1st kind of div with another one on the page (on the basis of text) and then delete the second one.

Comment: @Fede - Ok, so? I'm just asking for clarification.

Comment: try my code .it's working the way you want

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to do it, one way is to make a lookup

```
(function (){
    var lookup = {};  //store text here
    $("div").each( function () {  //loop through the elements
        var elem = $(this);  //reference to current
        var txt = $.trim(elem.text());  //get its text
        if (lookup[txt]) {  //if we have had this text already, remove the element
           elem.remove();
        } else {
            lookup[txt] = true;  //set the key in the lookup
        }
    });
}());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2qj4Lyz/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var divA = $(".A").text(); //gives you text inside i.e. Hello
var divB = new RegExp($(".B").text()); //gives you text inside i.e. Hello

//for matching 
if(divA.test(divB)) //returns true if matched 
  $(".B").remove();//for deleting div B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("div:not(.A):contains("+$(".A").text()+")").remove()
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/q5aok44c/

Answer (score -1):

I have written on button click. Just try it

```
<div class="A">Hello </div>
<div class="B">Hello </div>
<div class="C">Bye </div>
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn" />

 $('#btn').click(function () {
        if ($('.A').text() == $('.B').text())
        {
            $(".A").remove();
        }
    });
```